# is it possible to change the editorfor's values to display something else?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making an application in which you can assign which days you are working.

In my database, the data type of the column is `bit NULLABLE`, thus my Editfor displays a dropdown with 3 values: `Not set, TRUE, FALSE` but I want the editorFor to display the values `present` and `absent`.

is there a way to do this? Or is there no other option than to make a `DropDownList` and hardcode the values?

Comment: You need to generate your own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and use `DropDownListFor()` - the framework uses a built in (hard coded) template for a `bool?`

Comment: ok too bad there is no other way. post it as answer and I'll vote

Comment: well there are probably other ways but I assume you're giving me a solid one

Comment: If you want a dropdownlist as per the the default UI for a `bool?` - but of course you can use say radio buttons for selecting one of the 3 values.

Comment: But its a bit strange that you want the ability to select a `null` value in addition to 'present' or 'absent' (what would that mean)?

Comment: well I accidently set in the db that it is `nullable` haha, I'm not going to implement that as one of the options. And I didnt feel like changing it in the database yet. which I probably will do later on

Comment: What the type is in the database is irrelevant. Your editing data so you always use a view model, and the view model would contain a (say) `public bool IsPresent { get set; }` property if you want a checkbox